# MySQL: char_length(), wrong value for Russian

Tags: mysql, double-byte

I am using char_length() to measure the size of "Русский": strangely, instead of telling me that it's 7 chars, it tells me there are 14. Interestingly if the query is simply...

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('Русский')
```

...the answer is correct. However if I query the DB instead, the anser is 14:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(text) FROM locales WHERE lang = 'ru-RU' AND name = 'lang_name'
```

Anybody go any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I can confirm that the collation is utf8_general_ci and the table is MyISAM

Thanks,
Adrien

EDIT: My end objective is to be able to measure the lengths of records in a table containing single and double-byte chracters (eg. English & Russian, but not limited to these two languages only)

Comment: the collation is not the problem, you must know which charset the field 'text' has. (or the table default or the schema default)

Comment: I have checked and MySQL says that the "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"

Comment: SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  where table_name = 'locales'  and column_name = 'text'   (please use a reverse ' in information_schema.COLUMNS)

Comment: @Luis: I get two "utf8" as answer

Comment: that is the default charset for what? the connection perhaps, but the function returns the anwser with the column asociated information (its charset)

Comment: the two rows comes from two diferent db schemas, use * instead. but the problem is still the same :(

Comment: It does not say. It just outputs a column with "CHARACTER_SET_NAME" and the two "utf-8"

Comment: @AdrienHingert let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2585/discussion-between-luis-siquot-and-adrien-hingert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of two bytes is used for each UTF8 char.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

```
mysql> set names utf8;
mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('Русский'); result - 7
mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('test'); result  - 4

create table test123 (
text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
text_text TEXT) Engine=Innodb default charset=UTF8;

insert into test123 VALUES('русский','test русский');

SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(text),CHAR_LENGTH(text_text) from test123; result - 7 and 12
```

I have tested work with: set names koi8r; create table and so on and got invalid result.
So the solution is recreate table and insert all data after setting set names UTF8.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean to say

Comment: I meant that this one in UTF8 and you should set UTF8. Try to run 'set names utf8;'

Comment: mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('Русский');
+-------------------------------+
| CHAR_LENGTH('Русский') |
+-------------------------------+
|                             7 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('test');
+---------------------+
| CHAR_LENGTH('test') |
+---------------------+
|                   4 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I have tested work with: set names koi8r; create table and so on and got invalid result. So the solution is recreate table and insert all data after setting set names UTF8. Try this solution.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested:drop table, create table, set names, insert data, but I still get the same error. On the other hand, using your test123 table everything works as expected

Comment: I have tried extracting the same information using PHP's mb_strlen() and the result is still 14. Yet when I try to output the Russian text it shows correctly

Comment: Let me correct my last statement: using mb_strlen($row['text'], "utf-8") will give the correct answer

Comment: So you should set names UTF8 at first and than create a new table and insert data but not create table/set names UTF8/insert data.

Comment: Could it be that the actual data, having been entered in the DB through a webform, is somehow encoded in a weird way?

Comment: Yes you should always after connecting to db send the first query 'set names UTF8;' and then run any queries. All should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

the function return it's anwser guided by the most adjacent charset avaiable
in the case of a column, the column definition
in the case of a literal, the connection default
review the column charset with:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
where table_name = 'locales'
and column_name = 'text'
```

be careful, it is not filtered by table_schema

Comment: This query too returns two utf8 as answer